# How to write Razor code for List type entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My View Model is:

```
 public class CompanyAccountViewModel
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Interval { get; set; }
    public List<string> MobileNo { get; set; }
 }
```

and My view is:

```
@model PowerSupply.Models.CompanyAccountViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Register</h3> <br />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interval, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3 positioned_relative">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Interval, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            <span class="help-text">Hour</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interval, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            <span class="add-new-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="add_mobile"> </span>

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@id= "add_mobile" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group row new_mobile_wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="new_mobile_container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Here I all field is being rendered properly but:

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@id= "add_mobile" } })`

This does not generate any markup. I point out the reason and it due to the Entity Type. Entity Type of MobileNo is List. How to modify this  `@Html.EditorFor`? Any idea? It kills my whole day.

Comment: Are you looking for @Html.DropDownListFor?

Comment: No, I want to add one text field and then I will add additional text field  using jQuery, add validation as like single field.

Comment: This is how I've done it previously but my list was a collection of objects and not strings. Maybe this will send you down the right path?

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rate.Rate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Placeholder = "Rate" } })`

With model.Rate being a collection of Rate.

Comment: Are you planning to return the values to controller? If not then simple foreach loop will do the job.

Comment: You cannot bind an input to a collection. You need to generate an input for each value in the collection (in a `for` loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this property:

```
public List<string> MobileNo { get; set; }
```

Since a user may have multiple mobile phone numbers, you cannot bind this collection to a single `@Html.EditorFor()` helper (binding like current state doesn't generate any HTML markup). You need to generate the `EditorFor` helper for each `string` value by using a loop:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MobileNo.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MobileNo[i], new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" } })
}
```

Or use `TextBoxFor` as alternative, also inside the loop:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MobileNo.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobileNo[i], new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
}
```

If you want to create mobile number inputs dynamically from `List<string>` property, see [this article](https://blog.platformular.com/2012/03/13/dynamic-form-in-asp-net-mvc-jquery/) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because your MobileNo list has no data values when CompanyAccountViewModel was returned to the view.

Comment: No! Its because the property is a collection